# Date formatting using javascript not working on IE10

Tags: javascript

How do you convert a date or a string with this format '10-Aug-13' into 'mm-dd-yyyy' using javascript?

```
 var date =  new Date('10-Aug-13');
```

The code above returns Invalid date using IE10, but works well on other browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: not exactly what i needed.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the format of the string?

Comment: no, that's why I'm asking. :|

Comment: Also how would you determine the century of the year? If it's always going to be 20xx I'd manipulate the string so it reads "10-Aug-2013".

Comment: Will you help me manipulate the mind of the users?! LOL. They want the date on that format, and I'm asking you guys how can I convert it, please do not return to me the question. @_@

Comment: I think it fails in some cases because a century isn't specified. Even though the users can't set the century you could decide what the default should be.

Comment: It also failed with the century specified.

Comment: Did you remove the "-" characters? It fails if you leave them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use an external library? If yes, I'd recommend this one http://www.datejs.com/ , then you'd do something like this:

```
var date = Date.parse('10-Aug-13'); // works on IE8+, Chrome, Firefox, Opera
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the year will always be for the current century, which you can add as follows:

```
var currentYear, parts;

currentYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
parts = "10-Aug-13".split("-");
parts[2] = currentYear.substring(0, currentYear.length - 2) + parts[2];

var date = new Date(parts.join(" "));
```

However if you don't care about the century you can just default it to 1, like so:

```
var parts, date;
parts = "10-Aug-99".split("-");
parts[2] = "1" + parts[2];
date = new Date(parts.join(" "))
```

Also I've also removed the "-" from the date string as FF didn't seem to like that.

Comment: Still returns an Invalid Date on IE10 but works on Chrome & Firefox

Comment: I only have IE9 to test on but it works fine on that. Strange it fails on IE10.

Answer (score 1):

hope this js function below helps, the date parameter should always in 'DD-MMM-YY' format

```
function formatDate(dateparam) {
    var m_array = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var dtparts = dateparam.split('-');
    var dateObj = new Date("20" + dtparts[2], m_array.indexOf(dtparts [1]), dtparts[0]);

    var date = dateObj.getDate();
    date = (date.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + date : date;
    var month = dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
    month = (month.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + month : month;
    var year = dateObj.getFullYear();

    return month + "-" + date + "-" + year;
}
document.write(formatDate("10-Aug-13"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
date.format("mm-dd-yyyy");
```

Comment: try this on the console of your IE Developer Tool alert(new Date('08-Aug-13'));

Comment: try it also on Chrome and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date('10-Aug-13');
console.log((date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate())+'/'+date.getFullYear()+);
```

OR

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(8,10);
d.setFullYear(2013);
d.toString('MM-dd-yyyy');
```

Comment: The first line fails in FF.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date('10-Aug-13');
date = (date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate())+'/'+date.getFullYear();
```